Can we pronounce the word "English" without the /g/ sound, like Cambridge suggests?
Here's the phonetic transcription that I found in the Cambridge Dictionary: /ˈɪŋ·ɡlɪʃ, -lɪʃ/
Does the -lɪʃ part imply that we can also drop the /g/ when pronouncing it? If not, what does it mean?

FWIW, I don't find the American pronunciation there all that American.  Sounds to me like a British woman trying to sound like an American.

@TimR Sounds vaguely Polish to me.

Weird. I woulda thought the two possible pronunciations are IN-glish or ING-lish (using the NG sound). I can't imagine how you'd say it without the G but still sound like the same word.

@DarthPseudonym the symbol ŋ represents the sound written "NG" in "thing", or "N" in "think". So I don't think there's anything different from your expectation here.

oh, I missed that sign.  So the distinction they're drawing is between ing-lish and ing-glish.  That's less weird, I suppose.

Yes, that's what that notation means.
Phonetically speaking, since /g/ is articulated at the same position as the nasal that precedes it, all that could distinguish its presence is the release. In other words, the question is whether or not the release is required.
In my dialect (Canadian), it sounds quite odd not to audibly release the /g/. But I've certainly heard dialects where it's much softer, perhaps even droppable.
This same pattern applies to similar words like "linguistics".
There are also dialects that insist very strongly on the release, especially in the UK.
